# Scraping subfiles from URL using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

A webpage I would like to **scrape** consists of several files:

[image: webpage]

I'm interested of scraping only the highlighted file, that is: mboxFrame.

My method of scraping pages

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webPage = requests.get(URL, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webPage.content, "html.parser" )
```

is able to **scrape** only the file mail.html. Is there a way to **scrape** only what I want?

I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: Can you add the actual url / html source?

Comment: @Sureshmani do you mean what's inside the mail.html?

Comment: No. actual 'URL' used in your code. or the html source

Comment: @Sureshmani One need a password to log in this URL and unfortunately I can't provide that.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ not scrap.

Answer (score 0):

The way to open a file from a server is to request it with a URL.
In fact, in the beginnings of the world wide web this was the only way to get content: content creators would put various files on servers and clients would open or download those files. The dynamic processing of URIs and parameters is a later invention. That is why commenters are asking for the URL you use. We want to see it and modify accordingly to help you see what parts need changing in order to get that particular file. You can omit the password, or replace it with some other string of letters.

In general, the file you want would be under the url you use, but ending with the file name.
If the startong URL is `www.example.com/mail/`, then this file would be at `www.example.com/mail/mbox.msc`.

Please note that any parameters should follow the path, so `www.example.com/mail?user=hendrra&password=hendras_password` would turn into
`www.example.com/mail/mbox.msc?user=hendrra&password=hendras_password`